# Where can I read documentation on chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Where I can read what `request`, `sender` and `sendResponse` are? I want to get the content of the request but don't even know its fields!
Google leads me to https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/ and https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage but it doesn't tell what the objects are!

Comment: `request` is whatever you send in sendMessage.

Comment: Oh, thank you! But why isn't it in documentation?